# How can I store data when was deactivated event fired

Tags: windows-phone-7

When user click the Bing Search or Start button, this will cause Deactivated event.

So, when user press Bing Search or Start Button, How do I store the data. What type of Data can be stored and What to use to store?

Answer (score 3):

You can save:

- **Page state** (textbox values, scroll positions) by overriding [`OnNavigatedFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and writing values to the Page's [`State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.state%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property. You can reload the data in [`OnNavigatedTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- **Application state** (stuff that applies to all pages that you'd keep if the user hit back to return to the application, but not if they re-launched the application from Start) by handling the [`Activated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.activated%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) / [`Deactivated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) events of PhoneApplicationPage and storing data in its [`State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property. If targetting Mango, you can (and should) skip loading your application state if [`ActivatedEventArgs.IsApplicationInstancePreserved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.activatedeventargs.isapplicationinstancepreserved%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) is `true`.
- **Permanent state** (data caches, encrypted user sessions keys) to the file system using [`IsolatedStorageFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx). It's better to do this when you receive that data, rather than waiting for the Deactivated event as taking too long to write data can result in your application being terminated (and corrupting your isolated storage files)

Page/application state dictionaries can store simple types as well as dictionaries and any serialiazable class (which has an empty constructor requirement).

Comment: Pay particular note to the final point in this post. You only have a couple of seconds to finish up when Deactivated is called, if you have any reasonable amount of data you are better off saving it as you get it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "tombstone" your data. First of all, read about the [Execution Model for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

After that, read [one](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-13-what.html) of the [many guides](http://www.google.dk/search?q=tombstoning+wp7+guide&oq=tombstoning+wp7+guide) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsolatedStorage or the Application State environment to store information. Sorry to say, but start googling.. you would probably found this if you did.